# Calling one action from another action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on a Redux app in which many filter components can change the nature of a search to be performed. Any time the state of one of those filter components changes, I want to re-run a search action. I can't seem to call the search action from each of the filter components correctly, however.

Here's the main search action:

```
// actions/search.js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import config from '../../server/config';

export const receiveSearchResults = (results) => ({
  type: 'RECEIVE_SEARCH_RESULTS', results
})

export const searchRequestFailed = () => ({
  type: 'SEARCH_REQUEST_FAILED'
})

export const fetchSearchResults = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Generate the query url
    const query = getSearchQuery();  // returns a url string
    return fetch(query)
      .then(response => response.json()
        .then(json => ({
          status: response.status,
          json
        })
      ))
      .then(({ status, json }) => {
        if (status >= 400) dispatch(searchRequestFailed())
        else dispatch(receiveSearchResults(json))
      }, err => { dispatch(searchRequestFailed()) })
  }
}
```

`fetchSearchResults` works fine when I call it from connected React components. However, I can't call that method from the following action creator (this is one of the filter action creators):

```
// actions/use-types.js
import fetchSearchResults from './search';

export const toggleUseTypes = (use) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_USE_TYPES', use: use})
    fetchSearchResults()
  }
}
```

Running this yields: `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _search2.default) is not a function`. The same happens when I run `dispatch(fetchSearchResults())` inside `toggleUseTypes`.

How can I resolve this problem and call the `fetchSearchResults` method from the `actions/use-types.js` action?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I see 2 errors:

1. You're importing the `fetchSearchResults` function incorrectly.

   This is where the `TypeError _search2.default` is coming from:

   ```
   Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _search2.default) is not a function
   ```
2. You're dispatching the `fetchSearchResults` action/thunk incorrectly

**Error 1**: Incorrect import

```
// This won't work. fetchSearchResults is not the default export
import fetchSearchResults from './search';
// Use named import, instead.
import {fetchSearchResults} from './search';
```

**Error 2**: Incorrect action usage

```
// This won't work, it's just a call to a function that returns a function
fetchSearchResults()
// This will work. Dispatching the thunk
dispatch(fetchSearchResults())
```

Comment: Oh, this is great. Took me a little Googling to figure out how to call one action creator from another in different files using `redux-thunk` and this makes perfect sense now. Thanks!